# Регулярное выражение - всё между

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение

```
/x-x_x6x.format
```

Мне нужно выбрать всё до точки и слова формат (они всегда есть и одинаковые), само выбираемое может содержать слова, цифры и некоторые знаки, возможно пробелы.
Но перед может стоять или не стоять `\/`. То есть - так:

```
yyyyyy\x_6x-5 4.format
yyyy56/x_6x-5 4.format
x_6x-5 4.format
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look-ahead вам поможет.

```
(.+?)(?=\.format)
```

[Демонстрация в действии.](http://regexr.com?36l44)

Comment: @falstaf: Спасибо! А вы не подскажите, как сделать, чтобы всё между точкой и слешем? всё тут не нужно + слеш\вот тут выбрат.формат

Comment: Справился - Спасибо!